# How do I redirect from a view to a root URL in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I'm trying to add a link to my django site that redirects from the `catalog1` view to the `catalog2` page. So basically, I want to go from `.../catalog1` to `.../catalog2/other-page`.

All the other answers that I've seen require redirecting to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` first, and then redirecting to `catalog2`, but I've set up the site so that `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` automatically redirects to `catalog1`, so this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume, a situation , your `other-page` is `about`,you have `about` button in your path `http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog1`

catalog1.html

```
<a href="{% url 'about' %}">about </a>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
path('catalog2/about/',views.about,name='about')
]
```

views.py

```
def about(req):
    return render(req,'appname/anyfile.html')
```

So, by clicking on a button `about`, it will redirect it to that view which has `name='about'` in `urls.py` irrespective of any route.

Then you are redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/catelog2/about/` from `http://127.0.0.1/8000/catalog1`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you understood my question. I would like my url to redirect from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog1` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog2/other-page`.

Comment: by clicking on a button

Comment: You can use directly `name` of `other-page` in `url`  tag in `href` of anchor tag.